# Given an array of size 'n', find the max element in every window of size 'k' and add all of them then print the total sum as the output

Tags: c++, max

This is my code so far. I had a problem before, in which I was ignoring the last element of the main array, but then I ran the code in the debugger and fixed it.

It is working perfectly well for sample test cases, and some custom tests that I have randomly given it. But I am still getting a "WRONG ANSWER" verdict when I submit the code.

I am trying to avoid any built-in functions, like sort or anything, to reduce the time-complexity as much as possible.

So far, I have tried the code with 14 different test cases. It gave correct output to all of them. Also, there is no need to change the types of `int` to `long` or something, as the constraints are well inside the int bounds.

Any help to find the mistake in my code would be appreciated!

(I have also included the sample inputs and corresponding outputs at the end of the code)

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t=0;
    cin>>t;

    for(int z=0;z<t;z++){
        int n=0,k=0;
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);

        int arr[n];
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        int maxx=0;
        int ind=0;
        int tindex=k;

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            if(arr[i]>maxx){
                maxx=arr[i];
                ind=i;
            }
        }
        sum+=maxx;

        int tmax=0;
        for(int i=k;i<n;){
            if(ind>0){
                sum+=max(maxx,arr[i]);
                if(arr[i]>tmax){
                    tmax=arr[i];
                    tindex=i;
                }
                ind--;
                i++;
            }
            else{
                ind=(tindex%k)+1;
                maxx=tmax;
                tmax=0;
            }
        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    }
}
```

Sample Input

```
2
7 3
4 10 54 11 8 7 9 
4 2
11 15 12 9
```

Sample Output

```
182
42
```

Comment: please provide link to the task (judge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple testcase:

```
1
4 2
5 4 3 2
```

Proper answer is `12`, [your code prints](https://wandbox.org/permlink/efdcjqQHYV5Fu0br): `11`

```
max(5, 4) + max(4, 3) + max(3, 2) = 12
```

Basically the way you are calculating `maxx` is invalid and oversimplified.
Simple, but slow solution, has `O(n * k)` time complexity with `O(n)` memory complexity (to keep all data). You should start with that.
Harder, but fast solution, has `O(n)` time complexity with `O(k)` memory complexity (to keep only window data).